# Change HTML output of a view

Tags: 7, views

I have a view which displays products. The fields shown are altered via hook, and I want to add `<div>` and `<h3>`, when I find an appropriate field value. (I tried with adding style to the field in the UI, but the logic is somehow convoluted, so I would need to hard-code it.)

I need to encapsulate a complete row inside a `<div>` when some field has some value. I have tried with views-view-fields.tpl.php and views-view-unformatted.tpl.php, but they seem not to "talk to each other", so I am failing miserably. Maybe should I approach by using `views_view_result()` and building the HTML myself?

Answer (score 0):

To theme/design the complete row, you need to use **Style output** template file.

Click on **Theme: Information** in your view, in pop-up see the last file in **Style output** section. Copy the name and create file with same name and save this file at **sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/templates**.

Then click on **Style output**, copy the code and paste into the newly created file. In this file, you can add your own HTML display the result.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design the complete Row try **Row Style Output** which you found inside **Theme Information**

Try to create a file **views-view-fields--view-name.tpl.php** inside the themes/template folder and copy paste the content from **views-view-fields.tpl.php** file and design the view page yourself.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the theory is good, but the problem is that we have two separated files: one for each row of data, and the other file for each field in the row. I don't see that I can access to the data of one of the files from the other file, which is what is causing me the problems. Example: add in the view a field of taxonomy. Then in the tpl.php, just show the first instance of the taxonomy, and encapsulate all the rows of the same taxonomy in the same div.